# Kaa DataCollectionDemo not working

Tags: kaa

I downloaded the `DataCollectionDemo` (java version). It is throwing the following error

**Note:** My Kaa-sandbox server is running on AWS and there is no net-connectivity issue

```
$ java -jar DataCollectionDemo.jar
2017-09-18 06:24:59,181 [main] INFO  o.k.k.d.d.DataCollectionDemo - --= Data collection demo started =--
2017-09-18 06:25:02,869 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  o.k.k.d.d.DataCollectionDemo - --= Kaa client started =--
2017-09-18 06:25:04,868 [main] INFO  o.k.k.d.d.DataCollectionDemo - --= Temperature measurement is started =--
2017-09-18 06:25:04,868 [main] INFO  o.k.k.d.d.DataCollectionDemo - *** Press Enter to stop sending log records ***
2017-09-18 06:25:04,872 [pool-6-thread-1] INFO  o.k.k.d.d.DataCollectionDemo - Log record {"temperature": 17, "timeStamp": 1505696104869} submitted for sending
2017-09-18 06:25:20,770 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR o.k.k.c.c.i.c.DefaultBootstrapChannel - Failed to receive operation servers list {}
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to ec2-52-201-214-219.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9889 [ec2-52-201-214-219.compute-1.amazonaws.com/52.201.214.219] failed: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:138) ~[DataCollectionDemo.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:314) ~[DataCollectionDemo.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363) ~[DataCollectionDemo.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219) ~[DataCollectionDemo.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195) ~[DataCollectionDemo.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:85) ~[DataCollectionDemo.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108) ~[DataCollectionDemo.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186) ~[DataCollectionDemo.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) ~[DataCollectionDemo.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106) ~[DataCollectionDemo.jar:na]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.client.transport.DesktopHttpClient.executeHttpRequest(DesktopHttpClient.java:74) ~[DataCollectionDemo.jar:na]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.client.channel.impl.channels.DefaultBootstrapChannel.processTypes(DefaultBootstrapChannel.java:56) ~[DataCollectionDemo.jar:na]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.client.channel.impl.channels.DefaultBootstrapChannel.access$200(DefaultBootstrapChannel.java:32) ~[DataCollectionDemo.jar:na]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.client.channel.impl.channels.DefaultBootstrapChannel$BootstrapRunnable.run(DefaultBootstrapChannel.java:92) ~[DataCollectionDemo.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:72) ~[DataCollectionDemo.jar:na]
    at         org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:118) ~[DataCollectionDemo.jar:na]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you haven't enabled kaa management tab. After enabling it the  Amazon IP address must be given to the space provided and then update it. You can enable the management tab by changing the `gui_change_host_enabled=true`in `/usr/lib/kaa-sandbox/conf` with

```
$ sudo nano sandbox-server.properties
```